# Displaying textbox or label on an image

Tags: css, positioning

How to display a textbox on an image?(asp.net).
Like the way most id card are formatted.

Thank You!
Talley

Answer (score 0):

Look [here](http://frinity.blogspot.com/2008/06/placing-text-over-image-using-css.html) - it's about placing normal text on an image, but the concept is exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting style z-index="100" ?